# Hang Man Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Ok so me and my partner are trying to make a hang man game, but the problem we're running into is detecting if the correct letter is pressed, we have little tiny details that we need to fix as well, but that's the big issue. Our idea was to make x equal a different value when buttons are pressed, and then check if that's correct and play hang man of course, but now it's not doing anything when the buttons are pressed. Ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
import random as r

#Hang Man

class menu:
    def __init__(self):
        global game
        global play
        global canvas
        game = Tk()
        game.geometry('600x600+50+50')
        game.title("Hang Man")

        canvas = Canvas(game,height=400,width=800,bg='light goldenrod yellow')    
        canvas.pack()
        play = Button(game,text="Play",command=self.playbt)
        play.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def playbt(self):
    self.difs()

def difs(self):
    global easy
    global medium
    global hard
    play.destroy()

    easy = Button(game,text="Easy",command=self.easy)
    medium = Button(game,text="Medium",command=self.medium)
    hard = Button(game,text="Hard",command=self.hard)

    easy.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    medium.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    hard.pack(side=BOTTOM)
def letters(self):

    A = Button(game, text="A", command=self.A)
    B = Button(game, text="B", command=self.B)
    C = Button(game, text="C", command=self.C)
    D = Button(game, text="D", command=self.D)
    E = Button(game, text="E", command=self.E)
    F = Button(game, text="F", command=self.F)
    G = Button(game, text="G", command=self.G)
    H = Button(game, text="H", command=self.H)
    I = Button(game, text="I", command=self.I)
    J = Button(game, text="J", command=self.J)
    K = Button(game, text="K", command=self.K)
    L = Button(game, text="L", command=self.L)
    M = Button(game, text="M", command=self.M)
    N = Button(game, text="N", command=self.N)
    O = Button(game, text="O", command=self.O)
    P = Button(game, text="P", command=self.P)
    Q = Button(game, text="Q", command=self.Q)
    R = Button(game, text="R", command=self.R)
    S = Button(game, text="S", command=self.S)
    T = Button(game, text="T", command=self.T)
    U = Button(game, text="U", command=self.U)
    V = Button(game, text="V", command=self.V)
    W = Button(game, text="W", command=self.W)
    X = Button(game, text="X", command=self.X)
    Y = Button(game, text="Y", command=self.Y)
    Z = Button(game, text="Z", command=self.Z)

    A.place(x = 80, y = 550)
    B.place(x = 98, y = 550)
    C.place(x = 116, y = 550)
    D.place(x = 134, y = 550)
    E.place(x = 152, y = 550)
    F.place(x = 170, y = 550)
    G.place(x = 188, y = 550)
    H.place(x = 206, y = 550)
    I.place(x = 222, y = 550)
    J.place(x = 240, y = 550)
    K.place(x = 256, y = 550)
    L.place(x = 278, y = 550)
    M.place(x = 296, y = 550)
    N.place(x = 314, y = 550)
    O.place(x = 332, y = 550)
    P.place(x = 350, y = 550)
    Q.place(x = 368, y = 550)
    R.place(x = 386, y = 550)
    S.place(x = 404, y = 550)
    T.place(x = 422, y = 550)
    U.place(x = 440, y = 550)
    V.place(x = 458, y = 550)
    W.place(x = 476, y = 550)
    X.place(x = 494, y = 550)
    Y.place(x = 512, y = 550)
    Z.place(x = 530, y = 550)


def A(self):
    global x
    x = 'A'
def B(self):
    x = 'B'
def C(self):
    x = 'C'
def D(self):
    x = 'D'
def E(self):
    x = 'E'
def F(self):
    x = 'F'
def G(self):
    x = 'G'
def H(self):
    x = 'H'
def I(self):
    x = 'I'
def J(self):
    x = 'J'
def K(self):
    x = 'K'
def L(self):
    x = 'L'
def M(self):
    x = 'M'
def N(self):
    x = 'N'
def O(self):
    x = 'O'
def P(self):
    x = 'P'
def Q(self):
    x = 'Q'
def R(self):
    x = 'R'
def S(self):
    x = 'S'
def T(self):
    x = 'T'
def U(self):
    x = 'U'
def V(self):
    x = 'V'
def W(self):
    x = 'W'
def X(self):
    x = 'X'
def Y(self):
    x = 'Y'
def Z(self):
    x = 'Z'

def easy(self):
    ewords = r.choice(["TABLE","CHAIR","DESK","PHONE","LIGHT","MAN"])
    self.play(ewords)
def medium(self):
    mwords = r.choice(["PYTHON","LAPTOP","JACKET","VIDEO","MODULE","LIBRARY"])
    self.play(mwords)
def hard(self):
    hwords = r.choice(["PROGRAM","TOLEDO","UNIVERSITY","ENGINEER","FOOTBALL","LANGUAGE"])
    self.play(hwords)

def play(self,words):
    easy.destroy()
    medium.destroy()
    hard.destroy()
    canvas.create_line(100,50,100,500,tags="Line") #Vertical
    canvas.create_line(20,500,80,500,tags="Line") #Lower Horizontal
    canvas.create_line(100,50,150,50,tags="Line") #Horizontal Line
    self.letters()

    lwords = []
    for j in range(len(words)):
        lwords.append(" _")

    canvas.create_text(300,300,text=( "".join( repr(e) for e in lwords ) ),font="Times 16",tags="text")

    hm = 0
    x = 0

    for i in range(len(words)):
        if x == 0:
            continue
        else:
            if words[i] == x:
                words.replace(lwords[i],words[i])
            else:
                hm += 1
                if hm == 1:
                  canvas.create_oval(125,50,175,100) #HEad
                  canvas.update()
                elif hm == 2:
                  canvas.create_line(150,100,150,150) #Body
                  canvas.update()
                elif hm == 3:
                  canvas.create_line(150,125,125,100) #Left Arm
                  canvas.update()
                elif hm == 4:
                  canvas.create_line(150, 125, 175, 100) #Right Arm
                  canvas.update()
                elif hm == 5:
                  canvas.create_line(125,150,100,125) #Left Leg
                  canvas.update()
                elif hm == 6:
                  canvas.create_line(125,150,100,175)
                  canvas.update()


menu()
```

Comment: What is `self.A`? Where do you define it?

Comment: Just use an Entry to get the letter, and then: if letter_entered in word_to_guess:

Comment: Sorry but this code is way too heavy for something "simple" as a Hangman game. I scanned through your code and I would recommend you to read about dictionaries. It is the most efficient way to store data as key+value and becomes very useful to write lighter code. My tip: 
Have a look at it and rewrite your code.

Comment: I appreciate all the helpful comments, but this is for an assignment kind of thing, and we're supposed to stay within what we've learned, and using other modules and etc. isn't exactly what I need....

Comment: Basic widgets, like Entry, are used in most responses.  State specifically what you do need and what you can use.  No one is going to post an answer if they think you will just say "we can't use that".

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that, still new to this forum. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, whenever you have lots of repetitive code, use a loop or call a function repeatedly.  Here is an alternative using a loop to create the buttons using a command to call a function, and using partial to send the letter pressed to the function, so you only use one function.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial
import string

def button_pressed(ltr):
    print(ltr)

game=tk.Tk()
game.geometry("1000x600")
this_x=80
for b_ltr in string.ascii_uppercase:
    tk.Button(game, text=b_ltr, bg="lightblue",
              command=partial(button_pressed, b_ltr)).place(x=this_x, y=550)
    this_x += 33
game.mainloop()
```